# Disable button from onclick in angular, re-enable button when function finishes

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a button in myComponent.component.html that has an `click` method

```html
(click)="myClickMethod()"
```

controlDetails.component.ts

```js
    @Component({
    selector: 'removed',
    templateUrl: '../templates/myComponent.component.html',
    providers: [DataService]
})
    private DataService: dataService
    myMethod(): void {
      this.controlData = null;
      this.dataService
        .validate()
        .then(specificData => this.controlData = specificData)
        .catch(() => {this.controlData = this.getControlErrorMesssage();});
}
```

from `myComponent.component.ts` that calls an angular service that calls a backend API elsewhere.

How can I disable the button at the start of the onclick method and then when my API request is returned re-enable the button?

My Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private baseUrl = '/api/';  // URL to web api

    validate(id: String): Promise<ControlSpecificData> {
        console.log(this.baseUrl+id);
        return this.http.get(this.validationUrl+id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as SpecificData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: Introduce a _busy_ variable and bind _disabled_ attribute to it like `[disabled]="busy ? disabled : ''"`. Set _busy_ to true when starting the function and set it back to false, when the function finished

Comment: It depends how is your service if it's a sync method or async?, if it's async then does it return observable or promise?, this is why you need to provide a minimal code and also stackblitz link to be able others help you better

Comment: I think if it is disabled in the begining you can't click on that button. That means onclick event doesn't work. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aduavp)

Comment: You can disable it many ways. What have you tried?

Comment: Added some more info